# Printing stack traces

Tags: exception, ocaml, stack-trace

I have a very short test file:

```
let print_backtrace () = try raise Not_found with
    Not_found -> Printexc.print_backtrace stdout;;

let f () = print_backtrace (); Printf.printf "this is to make f non-tail-recursive\n";;

f ();
```

I compile and run:

```
% ocamlc -g test.ml      
% OCAMLRUNPARAM=b ./a.out
Raised at file "test.ml", line 1, characters 35-44
this is to make f non-tail-recursive
```

Why isn't `f` listed in the stack trace? How can I write a function that will print a stack trace of the location it's called from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code to do what I suggested.  I recommend using ocamldebug if at all possible, this code is much too tricky.  But it works on my system for this simple example.

```
let print_backtrace () =
    match Unix.fork () with
    | 0 -> raise Not_found
    | pid -> let _ = Unix.waitpid [] pid in ()

let f () =
    begin
    print_backtrace ();
    Printf.printf "after the backtrace\n";
    end

;;

f ()
```

Here is a test run.

```
$ /usr/local/ocaml312/bin/ocamlc unix.cma -g test3.ml
$ OCAMLRUNPARAM=b a.out
Fatal error: exception Not_found
Raised at file "test3.ml", line 3, characters 17-26
Called from file "test3.ml", line 8, characters 4-22
Called from file "test3.ml", line 14, characters 0-4
after the backtrace
```

I realized that because of the uncaught exception, you don't really have any control over the way the child process exits.  That's one reason this code is much too tricky.  Please don't blame me if it doesn't work for you, but I hope it does prove useful.

I tested the code on Mac OS X 10.6.8 using OCaml 3.12.0.

Best regards,

Answer (score 6):

The documentation for `Printexc.print_backtrace` says:

> The backtrace lists the program locations where the most-recently raised exception was raised and where it was propagated through function calls.

It actually seems to be doing the right thing.  The exception hasn't been propagated back through f.

If I move the call to `Printexc.print_backtrace` outside the call to `f`, I see a full backtrace.

```
$ cat test2.ml
let print_backtrace () = raise Not_found

let f () = let res = print_backtrace () in res ;;

try f () with Not_found -> Printexc.print_backtrace stdout
$ /usr/local/ocaml312/bin/ocamlc -g test2.ml
$ OCAMLRUNPARAM=b a.out 
Raised at file "test2.ml", line 1, characters 31-40
Called from file "test2.ml", line 3, characters 21-39
Called from file "test2.ml", line 5, characters 4-8
```

Comment: This answers half of my question, so thank you for that. Should I take the silence on the other half as an indication that it's not possible to do what I want, that is, to print a full stack trace and keep going?

Comment: I don't see a good way to do it without hacking on the OCaml runtime.  Maybe run under ocamldebug?  Or since you seem to be running in some kind of Unix, if this is just for a quick troubleshooting run, you can fork() your process and raise an uncaught exception in the child process (which will print a full stack trace), then exit in the child and continue in the parent process.  I did something like this in C years ago and it worked for me.  But it's ugly and likely to mess something up.  If you do try this (a bad idea probably), call _Exit() in the child to avoid flushing buffers.  Regards,

Comment: If compiled to native code you can try to use standard functions that print stack, e.g. libunwind or backtrace from glibc. Note that results may be not very pretty but usually enough to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I just tried using backtrace(3) and backtrace_symbols_fd(3) for the simple example above and the results (on Mac OS X) aren't very helpful.  It would probably be more useful with a larger example, but in this small case the only recognizable function name appearing in the backtrace is the C wrapper I wrote to call backtrace().  The  OCaml function f does not appear.  On the plus side, doing it this way seems much less likely to disturb the behavior of your program.