# Is it possible to break on a handled exception in OCaml?

Tags: debugging, ocaml

Debugging an OCaml program that has an unhandled exception is fairly easy, because the program stops running and you can obtain a backtrace by running in `ocamldebug` or setting the `OCAMLRUNPARAM` environment variable to `b`.  Is there any way to obtain such a backtrace for a *handled* exception?

Note: Modifying the program so it does not handle the exception is of course one option.  However, I'd like to avoid modifying the program if possible.  Something analogous to `gdb`'s `catch` command would be great.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function `Printexc.print_backtrace` that will print a backtrace showing the stack from the point the exception was raised to the current point where the exception is being handled. This might help, though note that it doesn't print a full stack backtrace.

I once wrote some hacky code using `Unix.fork` that prints a full stack backtrace on a Unix-like system. See my answer to [printing stack traces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599472/printing-stack-traces/7600069#7600069). (I wouldn't suggest using this code in production.)