# Printing backtrace doesn't work

Tags: exception, ocaml, backtrace

I have a block of code as follows:

```
try
   raise Exit (* body *)
with
| e ->
  Printexc.record_backtrace true;
  printf "Unexpected exception : %s\n" (Printexc.to_string e);
  let x = Printexc.get_backtrace () in
  print_string x;
  Printexc.print_backtrace stdout
```

The code in `body` does raise an exception, and it shows `Unexpected exception : Pervasives.Exit`, However it doesn't print any backtrace.

I compile the file with `-g` and `export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b`, does anyone know the reason why the backtrace cannot be printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see many functions in your code, so most likely there's no stack trace to print. See the previous answer here: [Printing stack traces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599472/printing-stack-traces/7600069#7600069)

It strikes me today that a likely problem is that OCAMLRUNPARAM isn't actually set in your process. It can be tricky to get environment variables to pass down through make(1) commands. One reason is that each line in a Makefile is executed by a different shell.

Another thing that affects backtraces is inlining. If your functions are complex this probably isn't affecting you. But you can turn off almost all inlining with `-inline 0`. It's unlikely that this would make the difference between no stack trace and stack trace. It might make a difference between shorter and longer stack traces.

Here is an experiment where inlining makes a difference:

```
$ cat m.ml
try
    let f () : int = raise Exit
    in let g () = f () + 2
    in let h () = g () + 3
    in let main () = Printf.printf "%d\n" (h () + 4)
    in main ()
with
    e -> Printf.printf "%s" (Printexc.get_backtrace ())
$ ocamlopt -inline 10 -g -o m m.ml
$ OCAMLRUNPARAM=b m
Raised by primitive operation at file "m.ml", line 3, characters 18-22
$ ocamlopt -inline 0 -g -o m m.ml
$ OCAMLRUNPARAM=b m
Raised at file "m.ml", line 2, characters 27-31
Called from file "m.ml", line 3, characters 18-22
Called from file "m.ml", line 4, characters 18-22
Called from file "m.ml", line 5, characters 43-47
Called from file "m.ml", line 6, characters 7-14
```

Comment: Actually, in the place of `body` there is complicated code, and the place where the radical exception is raised is in some other files, so there must be a stack trace to print...

Comment: OK, sorry! All I can think of is to make sure everything is compiled with `-g`. I haven't seen a failure like you're describing.

Comment: I copied your code into my `main.ml` and set the makefile with `-inline 0`, `-g` and `OCAMLRUNPARAM=b`, making files returns `Fatal error: exception Pervasives.Exit
make: *** [summary] Error 2`, but not the place where the exception is raised.

Comment: This is progress. You might examine the make output carefully to make sure it's issuing commands as you expect. Or you could try running my experiment verbatim. FWIW, my environment is OS X 10.8.4, OCaml 4.00.1.

Comment: I run your experiment verbatim, it works as you have shown... but I don't see anything wrong in the commands generated by my `makefile` either...

Comment: I revised my experiment so that it looks like your code, and it works the same as before. Possibly the problem is in the details of `body`.

Comment: Check that OCAMLRUNPARAM is actually set properly in your process.